# FastAPI AssertionError: DatabaseBackend is not running in test

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

```
TEST_DATABASE_URL = "MY DATA"

test_engine = create_engine(TEST_DATABASE_URL)
TestSessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=test_engine)


@pytest.fixture
def test_db():
    db = TestSessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

client = TestClient(app)


def test_read_company(test_db):
    company_id = "1"
    response = client.get(f"/companies/{company_id}/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I have valid connection to db at my backend, but tests can't run. I have error
"AssertionError: DatabaseBackend is not running in test"

I created test_db and use async, but doesn't works. Also if I don't have fixture test_db in the same file with tests, it doesn't works.

Comment: You're not using `test_db` for anything in connection to your app, so I'm not sure why it should do anything? You probably want to register the dependency override with FastAPI dependency overrides support.

Comment: Okay, I did a dependency override, but that didn't change anything